# How to share authentication between two asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, signalr, asp.net-identity

I already an asp.net application **A** use Web API and identity.

Now I would like to create another asp.net application **B** use SingalR, host on different server

So how the application **B** use the authentication in **A**?

Currently, my idea is to do something like OAuth, so if this is correct, how to do it in Asp.net identity? Or I have to write all things myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of way to solve this problem, but [JWT](https://jwt.io/) may be the way to go here.  You can use **Application A** to provide authentication (as you are currently doing).  **Application A** will return a json web token which you can use to authorize users on **Application B** assuming you use the same backing secret for them both.